# How to interpret chrome performance result

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, reactjs

I ran Chrome runtime performance recording and get the following

```
0.6 ms  Loading
17.0 ms Scripting
7.4 ms  Rendering
1.5 ms  Painting
26.4 ms Other
```

And I try to get its meaning.

- Loading means the time for uploading resources from the server
- Scripting means JavaScript executing time
- Rendering means the time delivering elements to Virtual DOM
- Painting means the time to update HTML DOM
- Other means ???

Is my interpretation correct?

Answer (score 1):

The "Other" is Miscellaneous Resources being loaded.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/performance/